# Mysql Query to replace WP post title with all_in_one seo post title

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**I want to replace the post title with seo title if it exists**

I would like to include `$wpdb->wp_postmeta.meta_value WHERE $wpdb->wp_postmeta.meta_key = aioseop_title` in the query below.
What I'm unsure about is what code to use to find if it exists or not.
For some posts, there is no aioseop_title.

Ideally, I'd like to list the post_title everytime, and include the `$wpdb->wp_postmeta.metavalue` if the `meta_key = aioseop_title` for each post.

What this is doing:  Below it's finding the post id to build a google news sitemap.
What I'm proposing above will use the seo title instead of the default post title in wordpress.

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results(
  "SELECT 
     $wpdb->posts.ID
     , $wpdb->posts.post_date_gmt
     , $wpdb->posts.post_title
   FROM $wpdb->posts 
   WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status='publish' 
     AND (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), post_date_gmt)<=30)
     $includeMe
   ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date_gmt DESC
   LIMIT 0, 1000"
);
```

Comment: I just don't get your point. Could you explain more clearly what you want (without all this BD stuff). Ex: "I want to add X meta-key in all posts based on it's title"

Comment: I want to replace the post_title with all in one seo title when it exists.  (this requires a join)

Comment: If I am understanding you correctly, a left join would work. Inner join requires all situations have to be met, left join allows empty (null) results.

Comment: Do you think a simpler strategy would be to filter the title when it is saved. If so, I can provide this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments to clarify, something like this perhaps?

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results(
  "SELECT 
     $wpdb->posts.ID
     , $wpdb->posts.post_date_gmt
     , $wpdb->posts.post_title
     , meta.metavalue
   FROM $wpdb->posts 
   LEFT JOIN $wpdb->wp_postmeta.metavalue AS meta ON meta.post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID AND meta.meta_key = 'aioseop_title'
   WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status='publish' 
     AND (DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), post_date_gmt)<=30)
     $includeMe
   ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date_gmt DESC
   LIMIT 0, 1000"
);
```

Followed by a conditional in php to determine if the aioseop (probably $row['metavalue']) column is null or not. I've not delved deep enough into wordpress to know the exact column names but from what you've put up this is probably what you're looking for. (As an aside it would probably be easier for you to alias the 'FROM $wpdb->posts' part as well.